# What tutorials does Dota 2 have except those via training available?

Tags: dota-2

I just encountered someone doing a last hit tutorial match, and now I wonder what other commands exist, since I was not able to find them.

Current I have - open console, enter

dota_tutorial_start lasthit

Are there others? (note, I am not interested in the ones given via the Play -> Training interface, but special ones like the lasthit)

Comment: I wish there would be a juking one. Like starting with 40 HP, having a hero with 150 HP behind you, and try to survive until you have enough mana to nuke him down or similar. Would be epic :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just scoured the internet and found this website http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=102493.

The commands for all tutorials are:

- **dota_tutorial_start lasthit**
- **dota_tutorial_start lasthit_training** – 10 Last and 5 Deny
- **dota_tutorial_start mid1v1_tier1_tutorial** – Destroy Tier 1 Tower
- **dota_tutorial_start mid1v1_tutorial** – Destroy 2 towers
- **dota_tutorial_start midonly** – Mid only vs 2 bot
- **dota_tutorial_start train_pudge** – Pudge Training
- **dota_tutorial_start tutorial_m1** – TUTORIAL: MECHANICS 1
- **dota_tutorial_start tutorial_m2** – TUTORIAL: MECHANICS 2
- **dota_tutorial_start tutorial_test** – TUTORIAL: TEST

*Note:* I actually don't play Dota 2 and got my info off the internet.